# Java: How do I create a getter method that gets an object from an inherited class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, getter, getter-setter

I'm trying to form a getter method of an object Mammal within a class Catalog.
The get method has no parameters, and has a return type Mammal (?)

```
public class Mammal extends Animal {
    private double intellect;
    private double hitpoints;

    public Mammal(String firstName, String lastName, String nickname) {
        super(firstName, lastName, nickname);
    }

    public void setIntellect(double intellect) {
        this.intellect = intellect;
    }

    public void setHitpoints(double hitpoints) {
        this.hitpoints = hitpoints;
    }
    public double getIntellect() {
        return intellect;
    }
    public double getHitpoints() {
        return hitpoints;
    }
```

I know it's a pretty simple question and you didn't have to see that, just giving context.  I coded several classes like Mammal, such as Feline, Birds, etc. and am the last part of the assignment, Catalog, a series of get methods.  I just need to getMammal, getBirds, getFeline, and the return type is either Mammal, or Birds[], etc.  So the object itself or an array of objects. My attempt:

```
public class Catalogue{
    private Mammal mam;

    public getMammal() {
       Mammal mam = new Mammal();
       return mam;
    }
}
```

so I'm clearly not understanding what to do at this step.  Any help would be appreciated!  The compile error I get is "invalid method declaration; return type required".  I'm trying it out in a few different ways, but can't seem to get past this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need looks something like this:

```
public class Catalogue 
{
    private Mammal mammal;
    private Bird[] birds;
    public Catalogue(Mammal mammal, Bird[] birds)
    {
       this.mammal = mammal;
       this.birds = birds;
    }
    public Mammal getMammal()
    {
     return mammal;
    }
    public Bird[] getBirds()
    {
      return birds;
    }
}
```

This creates a `Catalogue` with instance variables `mammals` and `birds`, and allows you to get those values.
And then to construct a `Catalogue`, you call:

```
Catalogue c = new Catalogue(mammal, birds);
```

Where `mammal` is an instance of `Mammal` and `birds` is an instance of `Bird[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public getMammal() {
   Mammal mam = new Mammal();
   return mam;
}
```

by

```
public Mammal getMammal() {
   Mammal mam = new Mammal();
   return mam;
}
```

You need to be explicit and define the return type of getter methods, as well as any non-constructor methods.

You might think it is obvious since you are *clearly* returning a `Mammal`, but Java is strongly and **explicitly** typed.

There are programming languages which can infer the return type of a method simply by examining the code, but Java is not one of them.

Scala, for instance, is strongly typed but can usually infer what the return type of methods is.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to get me further along.  But I fail at this step now because it expects a string,string,string input parameters. so I try Mammal mam = new Mammal(String firstName, String lastName, String username); but this does not work?

Comment: Is your catalogue class meant to generate Mammals, or simply retrieve them from somewhere else? If it generates them, then it is up to you. Maybe you want to create a Mammal with randomly assigned names?

Comment: Actually, why does your Catalogue class hold an instance variable of type Mammal? It seems you want to initialize this Mammal instance variable in the constructor of Catalogue and retrieve it later (you're currently trying to create a new one every time the getter is called)

Comment: I believe the purpose is to retreive from elsewhere, so there would be some other class, (I have a testCode class) that would call getMammal, but how is this possible if getMammal has no parameter inputs?  This catalogue has for example a mammal object, an array of 20 birds, etc.  I removed the instance variable, but my problem of needing 3 string inputs still persists

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but essentially you need to define a constructor for Catalogue which takes as input a mamal object, an array of birds and set those as instance variables of Catalogue. The getter must NOT call the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Mammal getMammal() {
    Mammal mam = new Mammal();
    return mam;
}
```

you have to write the type of object, that you will return. and to write in brackets "new Mammal(firstName,lastName,nickname)"

Comment: Could you add a code sample of calling the constructor correctly?

Comment: Mammal mam = new Mammal("Sheep", "Wilson", "Shep"); is an example of how I would construct a mammal object in a separate testcode class.  I still can't get this getMammal method to work though I tried public Mammal getMamma() {Mammal man = new Mammal(firstname, lastname, nickname); return mam;}

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly this Catalog class should be something to create instances of All the Animal type that you created.. one of the solution is simple and will be like:

```
public class Catalogue{

    public Mammal getMammal() {
       return new Mammal();
    }
}
```

You don't need Catalog to hold on instance.. Another generic solution will be:

```
public class Catalogue{

    public static Animal getAnimalByType(Class type) {
       return type.newInstance();
    }
}
```

And when you call this you will know the type.. So this will be generic.

```
Mammal m = (Mammal) Catalogue.getAnimalByType(Mammal.class);
```

The casting is required because in you generic type you will return Animal, so this will be generic and work for all animal types.. And when you call the method you know what kind of animal you want.. Because you passing this as a parameter in constructor

Hope that helps.. Of course this can be more sophisticated but this will do the work for now .

EDIT:

In order to create new instance of Mammal you also need to add construtor:

```
public class Mammal extends Animal {
    private double intellect;
    private double hitpoints;

    public Mammal() {
        super();
    }

    public Mammal(String firstName, String lastName, String nickname) {
        super(firstName, lastName, nickname);
    }

    public void setIntellect(double intellect) {
        this.intellect = intellect;
    }

    public void setHitpoints(double hitpoints) {
        this.hitpoints = hitpoints;
    }
    public double getIntellect() {
        return intellect;
    }
    public double getHitpoints() {
        return hitpoints;
    }
```

Comment: So i'm trying with your first solution and keep getting this error at compile: constructor Mammal in class Mammal cannot to the given types:| return new Mammal(); | with an arrow at new, required:String,String,String found: no arguments

Comment: Look on my edit.. This is because you need to add constructor to Mammal